# Data extraction using mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to retrieve values from the database using mysql and PHP.
The problem is :
+++ My table field (product_model_name) consist of (;) e.g Crystal;Uni and i want to filter results according to this product range.

I have tried to use mysql_real_escape_string() to deal with it but couldn't succeed.Here is my code:

```
$range="Crystal;Uni"; 
$test=mysql_real_escape_string($range); 
$sql="select product_model_image from product_models where product_model_name=".$test;
$res= mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
 { 
 echo $row['product_model_image '];
 }
```

Can anybody point me where i am making mistake??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 $sql="select product_model_image from product_models where product_model_name= '{$test}'";
```

also use the `pdo` or `mysqli` instead `mysql_*`

[Here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your string in quotes in the query:

```
$sql="select product_model_image from product_models where product_model_name='".$test."'";
```

---

Obligatory side note: `mysql_*` library is being phased out so you should write new code in another library such as [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). There are many other benefits to these libraries anyway, such as parameterised queries which are more secure than escaping as you are doing now.